# Hardware camera touch event ios

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

I am working on an iOS application where I want to check if a user touches back camera using Swift.

I am looking for these below events:

1. User puts and holds finger over phone camera
2. User holds finger over camera for 5 seconds
3. User removes finger from camera before 5 seconds

Please let me know if the above events can be detected in iOS application or not.

Answer (score 0):

Those Event above can't be detected. there are two kind of events can handled. 
1. Multitouch Event.
2. Motion Event.